# Is there a way to plot the groups that are set from R groupby?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataframe with repeating names in one column, and calculated values in the other columns. Is there a way to group by the NAME and plot all V1 (or V2) for the specific group? Or is there a way to create smaller DFs for each NAME (there would just be the corresponding V1 and V2 values for that NAME)?

Starting DF:

```
NAME      V1        V2
ctr        5         0.2
ctr        6         1.1
ctr        8         2.3
pd        25         0.7
pd        11         2.1
axs       12         0.8
axs       43         2.4
axs        2         1.1
```

Smaller DF example:
ctr DF would just be

```
V1        V2
 5        0.2
 6        1.1
 8        2.3
```

Comment: (1) Formatting your question (e.g., code) helps the way it looks, and gets people to think about your problem more quickly, please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. (2) *"plot all"* is a little vague, please demonstrate what you're considering. Is it merely `ggplot(x, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ NAME)`?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split` into a `list` of data.frames and extract it with `[[` or `$`

```
lst1 <- split(df1[-1], df1$NAME)
lst1$ctr
```

---

We can also do this with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>%
     filter(NAME == 'ctr') %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = V1, y = V2)) +
            geom_point()
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(NAME = c("ctr", "ctr", "ctr", "pd", "pd", "axs", 
"axs", "axs"), V1 = c(5L, 6L, 8L, 25L, 11L, 12L, 43L, 2L), V2 = c(0.2, 
1.1, 2.3, 0.7, 2.1, 0.8, 2.4, 1.1)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one plot, you can subset your dataset before plotting:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = subset(DF, NAME == "ctr"), aes(x = V1, y = V2))+
    geom_point()
```

if you want to have three plot one for each group, you can facet it by suing `facet_wrap`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = V1, y = V2))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~NAME)
```